# How to add all the list elements in custom field?

Tags: apex, community

I have a scenario where I need to add all the list elements in a rich text field. Please let me know the solution for this.

For example, I have a list which has 3 account details. I want to save all the elements of the list in a single custom field(Rich text).

Any help will be appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: where do you have the list elements? In another field? In Apex code? On a VF page?

Comment: Which type of list you want to update in your rich text area?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what's your complete use case and how you are going to use the converted string in the rich text field.

if its just one way, converting the list to string and leave it, you can do something like

```
List<Account> accList = [Select Id,Name from Account limit 3];
String strList = String.valueOf(accList);
```

but if you want to use the rich text string and convert it back to list, then you have to serialize and deserialize the list (JSON serializer). something like

```
List<Account> accList = [Select Id,Name from Account limit 3];
String strList = JSON.serialize(accList); 
List<Account> newAccList = (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(strList, List<Account>);
```